# Incorrect string length

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, serial-port

This may seem a little strange but I have this piece of code which logs my string and its length followed by it in a very simple way:

```
log.v("something", myString + " -- " + myString.length);
```

and very oddly what i see in my logview when program runs is:

```
.1.29 -- 9
```

im pretty sure my string doesnt have 9 elements here.

I have to say my full string does load from a serial bluetooth device which involves some weird characters but I make sure I bypass them through a function, though I cant filter them all out as it seems here.

Why do I see this contradiction in my string variables? and how would I anticipate that

Comment: In your code you are using `myString` but length is from `mString`. Is this your real code or just typo in SO question?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo in the question. I fixed it to myString, there is no mString.

Answer (score 0):

Possible errors:

1. You didn't specify what's in `myString` (at least in the code above).
2. You have `myString` but the length is from `mString`.

These could be the possible causes of error.

Comment: Sorry that must have been a typo I fixed it, it was not mString. there is no mString. Anyhow, my string is specified through a loop each time and as you can see its content are printed out. the problem is the length of that content. there is a contradiction. myString followed by its length that simple. is it possible that my string involves unsupported characters which it cannot show them therefore I dont see the rest of my string?

Answer (score 0):

String length is `9` in your case. You are doing concatenation of two Strings and then write it's length. `log.v("something", myString + " -- " + myString.length);` where `myString+' -- '` has the length of `myString.length()+ 4`, so You have `.1.29` which length is `5` and `' -- '` which length is 4 and that is `9`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing possible whitespaces?

```
  myString.trim().length
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably some characters are not being outputted in the logger for some reason.
Try this:

```
  for(int i=0; i<myString.length();i++)
  {
     log.v("something", "character number " + i + ": " + myString.charAt(i));
  }
```